# Qt creator doesn't build the project for android

Tags: android, qt, build, qt-creator

I have configured SDK, JDK, NDK on Linux Ubuntu. but when I attempt to build my project for android, theses errors occurs(All compile output):

```
18:28:22: Running steps for project InstaDL...
18:28:22: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
18:28:22: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
18:28:22: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
18:28:22: Removing directory /home/muhammad/Documents/qt_projects/build-InstaDL-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_0_for_Android_armv7-Release/android-build/assets
18:28:22: Removing directory /home/muhammad/Documents/qt_projects/build-InstaDL-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_0_for_Android_armv7-Release/android-build/libs
18:28:22: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" INSTALL_ROOT=/home/muhammad/Documents/qt_projects/build-InstaDL-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_0_for_Android_armv7-Release/android-build install
/home/muhammad/Qt5.9.0/5.9/android_armv7/bin/qmake -install qinstall program libInstaDL.so /home/muhammad/Documents/qt_projects/build-InstaDL-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_0_for_Android_armv7-Release/android-build/libs/armeabi-v7a/libInstaDL.so
18:28:22: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
18:28:22: Starting: "/home/muhammad/Qt5.9.0/5.9/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" --input /home/muhammad/Documents/qt_projects/build-InstaDL-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_0_for_Android_armv7-Release/android-libInstaDL.so-deployment-settings.json --output /home/muhammad/Documents/qt_projects/build-InstaDL-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_0_for_Android_armv7-Release/android-build --deployment bundled --android-platform android-25 --jdk /home/muhammad/Android/jdk1.8.0_131 --gradle
Generating Android Package
  Input file: /home/muhammad/Documents/qt_projects/build-InstaDL-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_0_for_Android_armv7-Release/android-libInstaDL.so-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: /home/muhammad/Documents/qt_projects/build-InstaDL-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_0_for_Android_armv7-Release/android-build/
  Application binary: /home/muhammad/Documents/qt_projects/build-InstaDL-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_0_for_Android_armv7-Release/libInstaDL.so
  Android build platform: android-25
  Install to device: No
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: Qt.Class
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Material.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.impl
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Controls.Universal.impl
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: /home/muhammad/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.4-bin/aeufj4znodijbvwfbsq3044r0/gradle-3.4-bin.zip
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
18:30:23: The process "/home/muhammad/Qt5.9.0/5.9/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project InstaDL (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.9.0 for Android armv7))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
18:30:23: Elapsed time: 02:01.
```

what should I do to fix it? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The key line in the exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout of 120000 reached waiting for exclusive access to file: /home/muhammad/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.4-bin/aeufj4znodijbvwfbsq3044r0/gradle-3.4-bin.zip`
```

At my previous employer, we had the same problem a long time ago (using *gradle 1.x*). It was either a limitation in *gradle* itself or in the way it was used (*gradle* wasn't **the** build tool, it was just a helper which executed tenths of times during a full build).
[[Gradle]: Gradle-1.1: “Timeout after waiting 120.0 seconds for Gradle Worker N to connect.”](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-1-1-timeout-after-waiting-120-0-seconds-for-gradle-worker-n-to-connect/2396/11) contains similar behavior.

But, according to: [[Gradle]: Running multiple gradle processes concurrently](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/running-multiple-gradle-processes-concurrently/7507):

> You can actually run two Gradle processes on the same project reasonably safely, **as long as they don't mess with what each other is doing** (e.g. deleting created files).

**One way** of getting out of this situation (that worked for me):

- Find the (*gradle*, *java*) process that keeps the file locked (maybe it's a previous build hanging) - you could use [[man]: lsof](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) to find out the process that locked the file - and kill it
- If the above step is not enough, also clean *gradle*'s cache

Comment: Did this answer your question?